# Geany keeps opening the same file when reopened

Tags: geany

System Info: Ubuntu 18.04.04 Desktop / Gnome 3.28.2

I have once, a while ago, edited the file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/guake/guake_app.py` and now Geany keeps opening this file everytime I open Geany.

It doesn't matter if I deactivate the options to re-open files from last session.
I also uninstalled geany through apt-get and reinstalled it.

Now I basically created the next problem by uninstalling geany and deleting every folder on my system with the name "geany". After reinstalling it, it won't start and complain that it can't find the file 
`/usr/share/geany/geany.glade`

I would really appreciate help with restoring the Geany installation. I would have thought that all the folders are being created when installing Geany with apt-get..

**edit**
I have solved my problem by installing Geany on a fresh Ubuntu and copying the missing folders over to the other machine, even though it would have been nice to find a solution to repair the Geany Installation on it's own. I don't know yet if the original problem (closed tab's re-appearing) will come again.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Im sorry, I was too quick. Of course you need that information...

Comment: You can try to install `geany` again, and after that purge it with `sudo apt purge geany`, and finally install `geany` again.

Comment: I already did exactly that, which left me in the described situation.

Comment: `geany` remembers which files were open last time. **Close the tab** of the opened file.- then exit from `geany`  and start it again. - What happens?

Comment: As I stated in the question, I deactivated the options to re-open files. Obviously I tried every possible way and combination of closing tabs and Geany first before going to the length of purging Geany.

Comment: +1; congratulations to the solution, and thanks for sharing it :-)

Comment: Looks to me like it's not Geany but restoring previous Desktop session issue.